# Raise Matrix to power C++

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I have written a function to raise matrix to a certain power.
But when running the code the result is the memory location not the actual values. I think the problem is with the pointers.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int array2d [2][2];
array2d A,B,r;

void pow(array2d* r,array2d C);

int main(){
array2d resa,resb;


A[0][0]=2;
A[0][1]=2;
A[1][0]=2;
A[1][1]=2;

B[0][0]=3;
B[0][1]=3;
B[1][0]=3;
B[1][1]=3;

r[0][0]=1;
r[0][1]=0;
r[1][0]=0;
r[1][1]=1;

pow(&resa,A);

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
   {
cout<<resa[i][j]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
}

pow(&resb,B);

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
   {
cout<<resb[i][j]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
}

return 0;
}

void pow(array2d* r, array2d C)
{
array2d temp;

for(int w=0;w<3;w++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
        temp[i][j]=0;   
        for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
        temp[i][j]+=(*r)[i][k]*C[k][j];
        }}

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
   {
    (*r)[i][j]=temp[i][j];
    }}
}
}
```

How can I solve this problem.

Thank You.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the results you expect and the results you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: first things first, why do you need 3 global matrix to raise a certain matrix to power ?

Comment: Raising a matrix to the power k means multiplying it with itself k times, not multiplying it three times with a matrix where all elements are k. And you never initialise `resa` and `resb`.

Comment: ok that's why, wp molbdnilo, the local and global r tricked my brain

Comment: You may want to write a small matrix `struct Matrix` which will have the double array. The you can write a member function `pow(Matrix& result, int power);`.

Comment: why a struct ? why don't really go into object then ?

Comment: @Guirox: A `struct` is a full fledged class, just with different default visibility of its members. As such a simple struct wouln't have any private members, there is no reason to prefer `class` over `struct` other than (maybe) consitency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you really should avoid global when you can, and using the same name in global and local variables is even worse

also the name of your variables MATTERS, here i call the input matrix IN and output matrix OUT (ok "n" should be called power)

```
using namespace std;

typedef int array2d [2][2];

void display( array2d a ) ;

void pow(array2d IN ,array2d OUT , int  n);


int main()
{
    array2d A,B;
    array2d resa,resb;

    A[0][0]=2;
    A[0][1]=2;
    A[1][0]=2;
    A[1][1]=2;

    B[0][0]=3;
    B[0][1]=1;
    B[1][0]=2;
    B[1][1]=1;

    pow (A , resa , 5);

    pow( B , resb, 2 ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
void pow(array2d IN, array2d OUT , int n )
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++ i )
        for( int j = 0 ; j < 2 ; ++ j )
            OUT[i][j] = ( i == j ) ;

    display( OUT ) ;    

    array2d temp;

    for(int w=0;w<n;w++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                temp[i][j]=0;   
                for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
                {
                    temp[i][j]+=OUT[i][k]*IN[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            {   
                OUT[i][j]=temp[i][j];
            }
        }
        display( OUT ) ;
    }
}
```

with

```
void display( array2d a )
{
    cout << endl ;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++ i )
    {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < 2 ; ++ j )
            cout << a[i][j] << " " ;
        cout << endl ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and the effort of writing the functions.

Comment: not sure this is the good way though, other answers seems better to me cuz they don't give the answers, but give clues about them instead, actually making you think and search

Comment: I do prefer explanations than direct answers. That is why I read and tried all the answers, and comment every one. I do know there was a problem with initializing and global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your error has nothing to do with pointers or addresses, but your algorithms is erroneous:

```
pow(&resa, A);
```

multiplies the matrix A with the uninitialized matrix `resa` which can yield any number of possible results.

The quick and dirty fix would be to initialize resa and resb as identity matrices:

```
array2d resa = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } };
array2d resb = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } };
```

---

EDIT or slightly better: Initialize r inside of pow

```
//passing r by pointer is not actually necessary here,
//but I don't want to modify too much of the code
(r*)[0][0] = 1; 
(r*)[1][0] = 0;
(r*)[0][1] = 0;
(r*)[1][1] = 1;
```

---

The more elegant solution would be to first multiply the parameter `C` with itself, store the result in `r` and then go on with your algorithm.

On a side note: don't use c-style arrays, if you don't need them (especially not in typedefs). Use `std::array` instead, which will get rid of most of the confusion regarding to parameter passing.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of your pow function, change it to the pass by reference: `void pow(array2d &r,array2d C);`

Then where you call it, call it like so: `pow(resa,A);`

Finally, you don't need to deference r in your pow function now, so `(*r)[i][j]=temp[i][j];` can be changed to `r[i][j]=temp[i][j];`

I think this is what you wanted to do. ( pass by reference )

( I am not in front of a pc where I can test this right now, will confirm as soon as I can, and maybe flesh out why this is better ( can read up about pointers, heap memory and pass by reference )

Comment: no need of reference here, you can just do `void pow(array2d r,array2d C);` and it behave exactly the same

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have changed the code according to your suggestions, but I got the following error: p.cpp: In function ‘void pow(int (*)[2][2], int (*)[2])’:
p.cpp:66:29: error: invalid operands of types ‘int [2]’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator*’
   temp[i][j]+=r[i][k]*C[k][j];
                             ^
p.cpp:73:9: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [2]’
  r[i][j]=temp[i][j];

Comment: your need need no `&` or `*` at all

Comment: @Guiroux I tried to remove & and *. And the output was incorrect. 611403232 611403232 
134312032 134312032 
216 216 
453312828 453312828

Comment: well try my code then it works, removing & and * aren't suppose to correct your mistakes, just they are useless, your mistakes are confusing about local/global variable r, you initialise the global one, but use the local one, which is not, initialised